Meaning of "break" in horse races
I'm a little bit confused by the word "break" that has a sense:

(of a horse in a harness race) to fail to keep to a trot or pace, as
by starting to gallop.

Can you give an example sentence for the definition? I need a sentence to grasp it.

Do you know what a "harness race" is?  Either you are a regular rider and take part in this kind of race often, or you will never need to use this sense of the word "break".  There are many common words that have technical and specific uses by very small subcultures.  If you are not part of that subculture, you don't need to worry about these meanings.  So, are you a horse rider? Do you take part in harness races?

@JamesK someone escaping from danger can suddenly break into a run. I don't think learning that meaning of break is a waste of time. See also: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/break-into

That's a related but different meaning of "break" this is quite specific  "of a horse in a harness race".  You could say "Jack broke into a run as he turned the corner"  But you  would not say "Jack broke as he turned the corner"

@JamesK You're right. Absolutely. But learning that specific meaning may help to understand idioms, phrasal verbs and fixed expressions with the word "break".

See the dictionary definitions for break (one's) stride and break ranks.

@FumbleFingers Do both mean the same thing as "break" in the definition above?

The question is badly posed: break into a [run, gallop, trot].

@Lambie: Not so. It's as James says, a highly domain-specific usage where equestrians might say His horse broke to mean his horse (which is in a harness race) failed to keep to a trot or pace, as by starting to gallop. Of course, even non-equestrians would understand His horse broke into a gallop in that context (assuming they understood that to avoid being disqualified, the horse must not "break pace").

@JamesK Harness horses are not ridden.  They are driven.  They pull sulkies.  See the photo in Michael Harvey's answer

That's the point.  I don't know about harness races, and unless you are a specialist you don't need to.  if you are a specialist, the you already know the answer.

@FumbleFingers The consequence of one's horse making a break is not usually diqualification.

In harness races (in which horses either 'trot' or 'pace'), if a horse changes from moving in the prescribed manner, by going faster, that is called 'breaking' or 'breaking gait', and leads to the disqualification of the horse and rider.

A second placing in the fifth and final race highlighted Kiwi champion
Blair Orange's opening day at the World Drivers' Championships in the
Netherlands.
The championships, featuring 10 drivers from all around the globe,
kicked off with five races at Victoria Park Wolvega.
Competing at his first ever world driving championships, Orange, the
five-time New Zealand premiership winner, started well with a fourth
in his first drive.
He followed that up with a fourth in the third race as well before a
second in the fifth and final race of the day.
On the flip side he was also disqualified in race 4, one of four
drivers to have a DQ [disqualification] on the opening day, after their horses broke
during the running.



Thanks a lot. Can you give an example sentence?

@Shakila - see update.

In general, a horse that makes a break during a harness race is not disqualified.  Rather, the usual rule is that it is not allowed to gain ground on other horses.  When a horse breaks, its driver pulls it to the outside and allows other horses to pass until it regains the correct gait and then it can resume racing.  I suspect that in the race in question the disqualification was because it was the World Driver's Championships.

Also, as you picture shows, harness horses do not have riders, they have drivers.

In this sense, the word break, in the broadest definition, means to change behavior, especially in a radical, extreme, sudden, or disruptive manner.

They broke their fast with a hearty meal.
John broke the silence with a loud fart.
The trotting horse broke into a gallop.
The newspaper columnist sometimes gave advice on how to break bad habits.
In a Broadway musical the actors frequently break into song.


Really? Farting jokes?

Good enough for Chaucer is good enough for me.

Cheap vulgarity is always in fashion…

You are revealing a cultural bias.  Go tap your demitasse.

:) Yes, proud to do so. It's good for learners to know that using certain words in speech will mark you as being on the vulgar scale. Unless you are a native speaker, the word fart/s will not sound spontaneous. Although "breaking wind" can be funny to hear... sometimes... depending on the pong.

Excellent example. But I don't understand "depending on the pong". I'm unfamiliar with that expression. The only "pongs" I know are ping and the early video game.  Is it the wind direction?

Must be BR... pong = stink, foul smell etc. +1 for all the other examples of usage.
